# Stored Procedure in Oracle with CASE-WHEN in clause WHERE

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, case, where-clause

I'm working in Oracle and I'm trying to do a Stored Procedure for a GET of data.

I want to insert a case when inside the `WHERE` but it doesn't compile me and the following errors come back to me:

- Error (11.5): PL / SQL: SQL Statement ignored
- Error (22.37): PL / SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword

**This is the procedure:**

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_S_DETTAGLIOLOTTI
(
    DATAINIZIO      IN VARCHAR2,
    DATAFINE        IN VARCHAR2,
    CODICEPROFILO   IN NUMBER,
    dett_lotti  OUT SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS 
BEGIN
    OPEN dett_lotti FOR
    SELECT A.IDLOTTO as IDLOTTO, B.S_DENOMINAZIONE as PROFILOLOTTO, A.TOTRKD as TOTALERECORD,
        CASE WHEN A.DATRPAPSA IS NULL 
             THEN 'NO'  
             ELSE 'SI' 
        END AS ELABORATO  
    FROM DLTOPST A 
    INNER JOIN REQUISITI B 
        ON A.COD_REQUISITO = B.COD_REQUISITI

      WHERE 
        CASE WHEN DATAINIZIO IS NOT NULL AND CODICEPROFILO IS NULL 
             THEN DATA_INVIO_POSTEL BETWEEN TO_DATE(DATAINIZIO, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24.MI.SS') 
                 AND TO_DATE(DATAFINE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24.MI.SS')
             WHEN DATAINIZIO IS NOT NULL AND CODICEPROFILO IS NOT NULL
             THEN DATA_INVIO_POSTEL BETWEEN TO_DATE(DATAINIZIO, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24.MI.SS') 
                 AND TO_DATE(DATAFINE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24.MI.SS') AND COD_REQUISITO = CODICEPROFILO
             ELSE COD_REQUISITO = CODICEPROFILO
        END ;

END SP_S_DETTAGLIOLOTTI;
```

where am I wrong?

Comment: "where am I wrong?" you cant insert case in a where clause

Comment: using if?

and if I had to do it in the where clause is there a way?

Comment: neither if, you can use `and `, `or`, subqueries etc. have a look at select Syntax in documentation https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may rewrite your `WHERE` clause as:

```
WHERE 
    (DATAINIZIO IS NOT NULL AND CODICEPROFILO IS NULL AND
         DATA_INVIO_POSTEL BETWEEN TO_DATE(DATAINIZIO, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24.MI.SS') AND
                                   TO_DATE(DATAFINE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24.MI.SS')) OR
    (DATAINIZIO IS NOT NULL AND CODICEPROFILO IS NOT NULL AND
         DATA_INVIO_POSTEL BETWEEN TO_DATE(DATAINIZIO, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24.MI.SS') AND
                                   TO_DATE(DATAFINE, 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24.MI.SS') AND
         COD_REQUISITO = CODICEPROFILO) OR
    COD_REQUISITO = CODICEPROFILO
```

The problem with your current approach is that the predicate of a `CASE` expression (i.e. what follows `THEN` or `ELSE`) has to be a literal *value* and not a logical expression.  What I have written above is one way to refactor your logic in a way that should work on Oracle.